# Sharing ConcurrentQueue but only getting the most recent value in consumer thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

So I have two threads one is receiving a stream of data from the network the other one is processing and sending that data out. The input stream is faster than the output stream. But it's real-time so latency is important to me which means I only want the latest sample value from the input stream when it's time to process in the output stream.

I have a `ConcurrentQueue` between the two threads:

```
public static ConcurrentQueue<RigidBodyData> sharedVector = new();
```

But, that has no way to access the end of the queue where the latest message is. So right now in the output thread I just loop through the queue until I get to the end and process that. I'm a little worried the input thread might keep updating the queue and keep my output from sending when it should. So I was thinking of making a new class that tracks the latest value and then just clearing it on a read, but I'm not sure if I'm breaking thread safety like this.

```
public class ConcurrentQueueWithLast<T>
{
    private ConcurrentQueue<T> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<T>();
    private T lastElement;

    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        queue.Enqueue(item);
        lastElement = item;
    }

    public bool TryDequeue(out T result)
    {
        return queue.TryDequeue(out result);
    }

    public bool TryPeek(out T result)
    {
        return queue.TryPeek(out result);
    }

    public T Last => lastElement;
}
```

I don't see how `ConcurrentQueue` handles locking which is why I'm not sure. Anyway does this seem like it will work? I don't want to make latency worse or cause myself race conditions. :)

Comment: How you getting "the most recent value" ? please provide minimal working example

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do here, but there does not seem to be a way for you to know if `lastElement` is still in the queue.

Comment: ConcurrentQueue is thread-safe. `Last` isn't and requires locking. You can use ConcurrentStack if you want access to the latest item.   Why do you want both a queue *and* the latest item? Who's going to inspect that latest item? The producer? The consumer? Will that item be "consumed" itself?

Comment: You could use a [BroadcastBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library#broadcastblockt). Dataflow blocks are typically used in a pipeline, with buffering and communication between them handled automatically. A BroadcastBlock keeps only the latest posted item but allows multiple consumers/blocks to retrieve it. With Dataflow blocks you may be able to get rid of explicit workers and queueing logic entirely

Comment: Especially for network and real-time processing it's *better* to create a pipeline of Dataflow blocks than try to implement essentially the same logic by hand.

Comment: Awesome, thank you I did not know about ConcurrentStack or BroadcastBlock. I'll check them both out.

Comment: @confused what about  implmeting a custom `dequeue`  like `(dequeue + peek (set last))` with `lock` ?

Comment: Honestly it sounds like you actually want a `ConcurrentStack` not a `ConcurrentQueue` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentstack-1?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 0):

> Anyway does this seem like it will work?

No. If the only thing you want is the latest value you can use a field for this. But then the concurrentQueue serves no purpose. You also need to provide synchronization to ensure it is thread safe. You should *never* share data between multiple threads without some form of synchronization, (with the exception of immutable/readonly data).

Something like this might work for a single reader and a single writer

```
public class TheadSafeLast<T> where T
{
    private T value;
    private readonly object lockObject = new ();
    private readonly ManualResetEventSlim hasValue = new (false);
    public void Write(T v)
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            value = v;
            hasValue.Set();
        }
    }

    public T Read()
    {
        hasValue.Wait();
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            hasValue.Reset();
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the reader will block if there is no unread value available.

The comments mentions [DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) and [BroadcastBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library#broadcastblockt), and that is a solution I would endorse. Especially if you are doing any complicated processing that might benefit from pipe lining or  parallel processing. Using existing high level tools usually help ensure the code is thread safe and helps avoids mistakes. Unfortunately I'm not experienced enough using Dataflow to write an example with any confidence.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some queue (producer / consumer pattern) why not use [Channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/channels) then?

```
using System.Threading.Channels;

...

public sealed class MyProcess<T> {
    private readonly Channel<T> m_Channel;

    public MyProcess() {
        // Channel with one (lastest) item
        var options = new BoundedChannelOptions(1) {
            FullMode = BoundedChannelFullMode.DropOldest,
        };

        // We want no more than 1 item, so we create bounded
        m_Channel = Channel.CreateBounded<T>(options);
    }

    // Add item (from input stream) to be process
    public async Task AddItem(T item, CancellationToken token = default) =>
        await m_Channel.Writer.WriteAsync(item, default);

    // Stop processing
    public bool Stop() => 
        m_Channel.Writer.TryComplete();

    // Items to be processed
    public IAsyncEnumerable<T> LastItems(CancellationToken token = default) => 
        m_Channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync(token);
}
```

Usage:

```
// Create processing
MyProcess<string> myProcess = new();
```

In the input thread / task:

```
// We add item after item
// Let me use reading lines from File as an example of input task
for (var item in File.ReadLines(@"c:\MyFile.csv")) {
  myProcess.AddItem(item);
}

...

// If you want to stop processing (no more items to process) 
myProcess.Stop();
```

In the output thread / task:

```
await foreach (var item in myProcess.LastItems()) {
  // Some relevant (slow) code which process item, e.g.
  var computeData = SlowComputation(item); 

  Console.WriteLine(computeData.ToString());
}
```

Please note, that you create *several* input tasks (say, reading from several files) or *several* output tasks.